# touchpad does not stay disabled

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

Is there a way to keep my touchpad disabled?

I have a thinkpad E420s. I have disabled the touchpad because the built in buttons are too hard to click without moving the cursor. I just use the red nubbin on the keyboard aand upper bottons instead.

For some reason the touchpad keeps getting enabled forcing me to go back to system settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> to set the Touchpad to off. I am not sure how to reliably reproduce this. It usually stays after a shutdown, or use of guest session but then sometimes it just appears on.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the reason for your mousepad being enabled again is that you push a certain key combination on your keyboard? I use a ThinkPad T420s, where the combination to disable the mousepad is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Maybe it works with your PC as well.

Comment: I don't think there is a combination to disable the touchpad on my computer. fn + F8 does F8 and just pressing F8 is screen brightness up.

Answer (score 0):

I use [touchpad-indicator](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao/+files/touchpad-indicator_1.0.0-0extras14.04.0_all.deb), install the deb, open it and disable touchpad